# Get the same response

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, asynchronous, windows-phone-8, response

I'm new in windows phone 8 developing. I'm trying to get response asynchronously. Last time i used [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577346/converting-ordinary-http-post-web-request-with-async-and-await/14711326#14711326) to get response. In my code this is looks like this:

```
 public async void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        cc = new CookieContainer();
        String url = "http://???/play/multi";
        String sss = await createHttpRequestMulti(url); //1st
        url = "http://???/play/check";
        sss = await createHttpRequestMulti(url); //2nd
        while (!sss.StartsWith("["))
            sss = await createHttpRequestMulti(url);
    }
   private async Task<string> createHttpRequestMulti(string url)
    {
        var myHttpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
        myHttpRequest.Method = "GET";
        myHttpRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        myHttpRequest.CookieContainer = cc;
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)await myHttpRequest.GetResponseAsync();
        var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string responseString = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
        response.Close();
        reader.Close();
        return responseString;
    }
```

GetResponseAsync looks like:

```
        public static Task<WebResponse> GetResponseAsync(this WebRequest request)
    {
        return Task.Factory.FromAsync<WebResponse>(
            request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null);
    }
```

Everything works fine only in first time i'm using StartButton_Click. In the second time 1st request works fine, but 2nd request dont even send request (i'm using fiddler), but says, that he did. And in result, i have result from 1st request. Help me, please.

Comment: Maybe it's caching the result. Try setting your request's [`CachePolicy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.cachepolicy.aspx) so it doesn't cache. (FYI, I'm just guessing here; I haven't had to deal with this issue specifically)

Comment: Like Chris said, caching is probably the reason. Try to append a value that changes on each request at the end of the query string, like that: String url = "http://???/play/multi?disablecache=" + Environment.TickCount;

Comment: Thank you, guys. You were right. WP caching responses with same url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
url + "?param=" + RND.Next(10000)
```

But i preferred:

```
    HttpWebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
    if (request.Headers == null)
    {
        request.Headers = new WebHeaderCollection();
    }
    request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.IfModifiedSince] = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString();
```

I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4461610/wp7-httpwebrequest-without-caching).